# When I try to use controlled data, schema isn't working at all

Tags: react-hook-form, yup

I'm working on a form with controlled components using state, but I don't understand how to allow my yup formschema working.
When components are uncontrolled, it works like a charm. But when I try to use controlled data, schema isn't working at all.

The code of App.js :

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup'
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {

    const formSchema = Yup.object().shape({
        address_1: Yup.string()
            .required("Field is required")
            .max(10, "Field too long"),
    });

    const formOptions = {
        resolver: yupResolver(formSchema),
        mode: 'onChange',
        defaultValues: {
            address_1: "My address",
        }
    };
    const {
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
        control,
        register
    } = useForm(formOptions);

    const onSubmit = (data) => {
        console.log(address1);
    }

    const [address1, setAddress1] = useState( "My address" );

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <div className="row mt-3">
                    <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                        <Controller
                                name="address_1"
                                control={control}
                                render={({ field, formState }) => (
                                    <TextField
                                            {...field}
                                            fullWidth
                                            required
                                            label="Insert an address"
                                            error={!!formState.errors?.address_1}
                                            helperText={formState.errors?.address_1?.message}
                                            value={address1}
                                            onChange={(event) => setAddress1( event.target.value )}
                                    />
                                )}
                        />
                        <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here is a [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-newton-9jp8tg?file=/src/App.js) to demonstrate the implementation. The unique field must be required and with a maximum of characters of 10 characters. I tried a lot of combination, but I'm actually not able to find my mistake.

If anyone has a suggestion or a sample to let me understand what I'm missing... :-)

Thanks in advance for any help on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it can be solved.
Please **comment out** as follows...

```
// value={address1}
// onChange={(event) => setAddress1(event.target.value)}
```

The reason is that `TextField` does not try to connect to react-hook-form,   but connects to "state".
In this case, the following state seems unnecessary

```
const [address1, setAddress1] = useState ("My address");
```

I tried, but the schema worked fine